why meditation is for 1 hour
Why people recommend to sit in meditation for 1 hour not 55 mins 59 mins or 61 mins .Is it something special for 60 mins ?
Can I use binaural beats in headphone  while meditating ?

Why do you think that one can only meditate for 1 hour?

Perhaps your question is referring to this previous question of yours -- length vs number of times of meditation -- to which one answer starts with, "Shoot for the hour". In that context, that answer is not saying "Don't meditate for 59 or 61 minutes" -- it's saying, "one 60-minute period is better than six 10-minute periods". It also explains why it says that, in its next sentence i.e., "It takes the mind about 25–30 minutes to really settle. It’s a lot like impurities settling out of a glass of water.".

Binaural beats in headphone is not Buddhist meditation.
I guess "one hour" is similar to when you visit a therapist or pay for a tradesperson to fix something in your house. They charge fees by the hour.
